# Set Headers when Ingesting from Nifi into MarkLogic Data Hub

Tags: marklogic, apache-nifi, marklogic-dhf

When I ingest a document into the MarkLogic Data Hub, then some headers are created automatically in the JSON document.
Example:

```
"headers": {
  "sources": [
    {
      "name": "customer-db-a"
    }
  ],
  "createdOn": "2020-03-11T13:31:28.6069705+01:00",
  "createdBy": "admin"
}
```

Is it possible to set the header of the source dynamically, when I ingest from Apache Nifi (with the mlRunIngest transformation)?
I would like to reuse the same ingestion step for multiple sources.

Comment: Are you referencing the same step in both QuickStart and NiFi? The headers will come from the step options, though createdUsingFile is specific to ingesting CSV via QuickStart or Gradle.

Comment: @rjrudin: I've updated to the latest version (data hub 5.2) and recreated the ingestion step. Now the headers are created. 
Thus I have updated my question to pinpoint what I actually want to do: to dynamically set the source.

Comment: The "options" param, if set, is expected to be a JSON object that can add to and override the step options. So try setting headers.sources in a JSON object that is the value of the "options" param, which I believe is trans:param in the NiFi processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nifi, in the MarkLogic processor, a custom property named "trans:options" can be used to pass in JSON headers. In the headers, the sources can be defined.

Example:
[image]

Additionally, the placeholders *currentDateTime* and *currentUser* can be used in the header for setting the current timestamp and the current user:

```
{
    "headers" : {
      "sources" : [
        {
            "name": "my-nifi-source"
        }
      ],
      "createdOn" : "currentDateTime",
      "createdBy" : "currentUser"
    }
}
```